# Transform each entryset of a Map to another Custom Object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've a POJO called Company1:

```
public class Company1 {
    private String companyName;
    private String job;
    private int age;
}
```

I receive a `Map<String, List<Company1>>` from a remote API. My requirement is to transform each entrySet of this Map to another object (say `Company2`) which has the following structure:

```
public class Company2 {
    private String companyName;
    private List<String> jobs;
    private List<Integer> ages;
}
```

How can I do this conversion using the Stream API?

Comment: What is the desired result? a `List<Company2>` or a `Map<String, Company2>` ?

Comment: And what if the `Company1` objects have different values for `companyName` field?

Comment: List<Company2> is the desired result. Company1 can have different value for Company Name field. The key in the Map<String,List<Company1>> is actually the companyName.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your classes have implemented the getters for the mentioned fields and `Company2` has a constructor which looks something like

```
Company2(String companyName, List<String> jobs, List<Integer> ages){
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.jobs = jobs;
    this.ages = ages;
}
```

one way could be:

```
List<Company2> result = 
     yourMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> new Company2 (entry.getKey(),
                                    entry.getValue().stream().map(Company1::getJob).collect(collectors.toList()),
                                    entry.getValue().stream().map(Company1::getAge).collect(collectors.toList()))
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You could also move the logic to `Company2`s constructor to make the above more readable, by first creating a constructor which accepts a string and a list of `Company1` objects:

```
Company2(String companyName, List<Company1> comp){
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.jobs = comp.stream().map(Company1::getJob).collect(collectors.toList());
    this.ages = comp.stream().map(Company1::getAge).collect(collectors.toList());
}
```

and stream over your map like

```
List<Company2> result = 
     yourMap.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> new Company2 (entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That's actually a very nice approach, but the only concern that I have is that the Company list is being iterated twice to set jobs list and ages list. I was wondering whether there's a way to open one stream and set jobs list and ages list in one go.

Comment: I don't think you need to worry much about this, as I doubt that your list contains millions of entries. I didn't know how to do it on the quick and easy way. There is certainly a workaround to make it happen. But then you had to use a `List<Object>` because your fields have different types, which you have to cast awkwardly when you access the data. A possible clean way would be this example: [split-list-of-objects-into-multiple-lists-of-fields-values-using-java-streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60266230/split-list-of-objects-into-multiple-lists-of-fields-values-using-java-streams)

Answer (score -2):

You could use the map method to create a list of other objects.
Here is a good example: https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-streams-map-examples/